# How can i exclude ignore_throttled' param in HighLevelClient

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch

`I currently use ElasticSearch in Spring Boot. The ES version is 6.2.2 and an error occurs because an option such as ignore_throttle does not exist. When I check the library version, it is judged that the high level client 7.x version is the problem, but if I change the version to 6.2.2, an unknown error occurs and I just try to use it. Could you possibly delete the parameter?`

implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch:2.1.10.RELEASE'

request

```
SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
sourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery());
searchRequest.source(sourceBuilder);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the version of spring boot you are using > 2.1.5

Comment: If yes, consider using the Java Low Level REST Client

Or downgrade spring boot to 2.1.5